# Perform multiple mocha tests after single expensive operation (e.g. HTTP GET)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

If I have a set of URLs to visit:

```
let tests = [
  { status: 200, mediaType: 'text/html', req: { method: 'GET', uri: 'http://stackoverflow.com/' } },
  { status: 200, mediaType: 'text/html', req: { method: 'GET', uri: 'http://stackoverflow.com999/' } },
  { status: 200, mediaType: 'text/html', req: { method: 'GET999', uri: 'http://stackoverflow.com/' } },
]
```

and a set of tests to perform on each:

```
it('should have status ' + test.status, () => {
  expect(test.response.statusCode).to.equal(test.status)
})
it('should have content type ' + test.mediaType, () => {
  let s = test.response.headers['content-type']
  let mediaType = s.indexOf(';') === -1 ? s : s.substr(0, s.indexOf(';'))
  expect(mediaType).to.equal(test.mediaType)
})
it('should have a body', () => {
  expect(test.body).to.not.equal('')
})
```

How can I perform the expensive operation only once per set of tests? Also, I don't want to run the tests if the URL doesn't load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [mocha `Working With Promises` documentation](http://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises) has an example with each (of one, admittedly) test waits for a `beforeEach` promise to complete before executing. If you need a `beforeEach` anyways, you can save that promise for the `beforeEach`, you can have them all wait for one promise:

```
let P = null
beforeEach(function () {
  if (!P) P = new Promise(...)
  return P
})
```

but more likely, you'll just want to use a `before`:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  return new Promise(...)
})
```

For a complete listing of the problem:

```
let expect = require('chai').expect
let request = require('request')

let tests = [
  { status: 200, mediaType: 'text/html', req: { method: 'GET', uri: 'http://localhost/' } },
  { status: 200, mediaType: 'text/html', req: { method: 'GET', uri: 'http://localhost999/' } },
  { status: 200, mediaType: 'text/html', req: { method: 'GET999', uri: 'http://localhost/' } },
]

tests.forEach(function (test) {
  describe(test.req.method + ' ' + test.req.uri, function () {
    before('should load', function() {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request(test.req, function (error, response, body) {
          if (error) {
            reject(test.rejection = error)
          } else {
            test.response = response
            test.body = response
            resolve()
          }
        })
      })
    });

    it('should have status ' + test.status, () => {
      expect(test.response.statusCode).to.equal(test.status)
    })
    it('should have content type ' + test.mediaType, () => {
      let s = test.response.headers['content-type']
      let mediaType = s.indexOf(';') === -1 ? s : s.substr(0, s.indexOf(';'))
      expect(mediaType).to.equal(test.mediaType)
    })
    it('should have a body', () => {
      expect(test.body).to.not.equal('')
    })
  })
})
```

This gives you pretty fluent output:

```
  GET http://stackoverflow.com/
    ✓ should have status 200
    ✓ should have content type text/html
    ✓ should have a body

  GET http://stackoverflow.com999/
    1) "before each" hook: should load for "should have status 200"

  GET999 http://stackoverflow.com/
    ✓ should have status 200
    ✓ should have content type text/html
    ✓ should have a body
```

If you change the example to use localhost intead of stackoverflow, you can watch the access log to verify that each URL is loaded once:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Oct/2017:06:52:10 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12482 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Oct/2017:06:52:10 -0400] "GET999 / HTTP/1.1" 501 485 "-" "-"
```

Note that the last operation, `GET999 http://stackoverflow.com/` gives a 200 on stackoverflow (via a varnish cache) and a 501 on apache:

```
  2) GET999 http://localhost/
       should have status 200:

      AssertionError: expected 501 to equal 200
      + expected - actual

      -501
      +200
```

Comment: Why not just use `before`?

Comment: That is indeed better. I updated the answer using `before`. Tx!